# Word for mouthpart that doesn’t imply that it applies to the mouth

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, biology

Is there a word that refers to the organs/appendages used for processing food that do not imply that the organ/appendage in question is around a mouth or other orifice for food?

Example sentence:

> The hammerhead worm's _______ are placed upon its head

Comment: You'd have to be thinking of alternative ways organisms access food. Perhaps engulfing (amoebas) or absorption (the Pacific hagfish). But specific organs (not counting the skin) aren't involved.

Comment: First part of the digestive system?

Answer (score 1):

**Mouth** is the usual term for the aperture through which food is ingested regardless of body structure. This applies even in creatures like the jellyfish which have no head, and where the mouth is situated on the underside of their body. For instance, the [American Museum of Natural History](https://www.amnh.org/explore/news-blogs/news-posts/anatomy-of-a-jellyfish) explains:

> Among their many tentacles, some jellyfish have parts known as oral arms. These long appendages move captured prey to the animal’s mouth, which is usually found on the underside of the bell.

[National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/invertebrates/facts/sea-anemones) describes the sea anemone:

> Their bodies are composed of an adhesive pedal disc, or foot, a cylindrical body, and an array of tentacles surrounding a central mouth.

The zoologist Louis Agassiz [described](http://courses.washington.edu/mareco07/students/nina/barnacleshome.html) the barnacle as attached to a rock by its head and ingesting food at the other end:

> nothing more than a little shrimp-like animal, standing on its head in a limestone house and kicking food into its mouth.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a single word, but I really doubt there is one. The term ***gastrovascular cavity*** is used to describe the digestive system of certain invertebrates, such as jellyfish and flatworms:

> functioning in both digestion and circulation
>
> - the ***gastrovascular cavity*** of a jellyfish ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gastrovascular#:%7E:text=%3A%20functioning%20in%20both%20digestion%20and%20circulation))

[BYUS.com](https://byjus.com/question-answer/what-are-three-functions-of-a-cnidarians-gastrovascular-cavity/) explains

> The ***gastrovascular cavity*** is the *major site for food digestion and nutrient absorption in [cnidarians](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cnidarian)*. Food passes through the mouth and enters the cavity. Inside the gastrovascular cavity, a cell membrane wraps around food particles and then takes them to the interior cavity.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastrovascular_cavity#:%7E:text=The%20gastrovascular%20cavity%20is%20the,into%20a%20system%20of%20canals.) confirms that

> The ***gastrovascular cavity*** is *the primary organ of digestion and circulation* in two major animal phyla: the Coelenterates or cnidarians (including jellyfish and corals) and ***Platyhelminthes (flatworms)***. The cavity may be extensively branched into a system of canals.

The organs that ***sense*** food are called ***auricles***, because they look like ears. Were you maybe thinking of those? About *Planarians* (flat-worms) [exploringnature](https://www.exploringnature.org/db/view/Platyhelminthes-Flatworms) says

> They have a head, brain and sense organs. This is called “cephalization.” They also have points on either side of the head that look a bit like ears, called “sensory lobes” or ***auricles***. They do not hear, but ***can sense food***.